# Adding an audio track to a video using it's own audio as a source?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file with the following layout:

- Video
- DTS audio

What I would like to do is:

- Video
- AAC audio (converted from the DTS source)
- DTS audio

I can't wrap my head around the FFMPEG command I would need to do this, though, since I would need to convert the DTS audio to AAC and then place it ahead of the DTS track.  The reason for this is the PS4 media player currently doesn't let you select audio tracks and it only plays the first one it sees.  It doesn't support DTS audio but I'd like to keep it around.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out after looking FFMPEG's map documentation: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map

The solution was this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -c:a:1 copy out.mkv
```

The trick was mapping the audio stream twice and using the `-c:a:x` syntax to encode the DTS stream to AAC first and then copy the DTS stream second in the output file.